# When merging a branch, gitlab updates both branches

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I have 2 branches:

- **development** branch (is the default)
- **5-feature-branch** (which is a feature longlasting)

After some time I want to make a git merge from development to 5-feature, just to update my longlasting feature branch.

I use Gitlab GUI to do that - simple merge, no-ff enabled, squash commits.

**My expectations:**

- development branch stays unaffected
- I see a merge of 2 branches in the 5-feature-branch

**What happens** (looking at Graph history)

- 5-featurue-branch is merged to development branch
- development branch is merged to the 5-feature branch

Git diff development..5-feature-branch is showing no differences.

```
BEFORE       EXPECTAT        REALITY
                                 x
                               / |
                              /  |
                 x           x   |
               / |           | \ |
              /  |           |  \|
x   x        x   x           x   x
|   |        |   |           |   |
|   |        |   |           |   |
|   |        |   |           |   |
dev  5-f     dev  5-f        dev  5-f
```

Was there a bug in Gitlab that did this? (not totally updated).
Testing this with a commandline works as expected.

```
$ git checkout 5-feature-branch
$ git merge --no-ff development
# FIX conflicts
$ git commit
```

Comment: It appears that someone did a merge of `5-f` into `dev` in GitLab before you merged it back the other way. Maybe you just didn't know this happened? Try `git fetch` locally to make sure you're working with the latest `origin/development` branch. In your "REALITY" graph, the top left side commit might tell you who did it and when.

Comment: I am pretty sure this did not happen. I did plenty of experiments with this. I've  cloned repositories to my private repository to give it a try, i've followed ther same commands as stated on the gitlab. The problem is repeatable.

Comment: Does the extra commit contain any information in it that is useful? (Author, datetime, message, etc?)